# Building a Tutorial/Giving a hint for my Android app

Tags: java, android, tooltip

I am building an android app and I want the app to show up some tutorial dialogs or speech balloons at first use.

I decided to use the Preferences and store a boolean for each Activity. When it is first shown the balloon should popup.
But I have no clue how to draw a balloon or make an InApp-Tutorial.

Thank you and best regards,
Till

Answer (score 1):

You can use toasts. and use the shared preferences to check wether or not the users should be seeing the tutorial.
[Heres a link to the dev.android page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html)

Theyre just little boxes that pop up for a certain time.

just have them pop up on certain events (if its a game), or let them pop up one after the other.  EASY!!!
hope this helps!